# how to save text into a txt file using python 2.7 using tk

Tags: python, button, tkinter, save

Im using tkinter and I am trying to get text that's entered by a user to be saved into a existing txt file when they click on save, any ideas.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

w1 = Label(root, text="Username")
w1.pack()

e = Entry(root)
e.pack()

w2 = Label(root, text="Password")
w2.pack()

e1 = Entry(root)
e1.pack()

toolbar = Frame(root)

b = Button(toolbar, text="save", width=9)
b.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)

toolbar.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to create a function that is called when the save button is clicked. Put it near the top of your script and then set it as the button's `command`.

```
def save():
    text = e.get() + " " + e1.get() + "\n"
    with open("text.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(text)

# Snip

b = Button(toolbar, text="save", width=9, command=save)
```